# Overlap Multiple Images In A Row

Tags: css, overlap

I know there are several threads on the "overlapping images" topic, but I can't find one that addresses my specific problem.

I have five circular images and I need to display them with slight overlap, kind of like how a deck of cards looks when it's laid out in a fan.

Here is what it should look like:
[image]

Here is what I currently have:
[image]

All the code examples I've found are aimed at overlapping two square images and I can't figure out how to translate to this scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried messing around with grid layout and negative margins, but it was just a huge mess.

I can't share the source code but I've recreated the exact same HTML/CSS with dummy data [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/NWvgmVM).

Code:

```css
.main-container {
  height: fit-content;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

#icons-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div id="icons-container">
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon1" />
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon2" />
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon3" />
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon4" />
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon5" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Check this article, it might help](https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/how-to-layer-profile-images-over-one-another.stml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `margin-right`/`margin-left` on the `icon` . To overlap, let `margin-right` have negative values

```css
.main-container {
  height: fit-content;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

#icons-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div id="icons-container">
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon1">
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon2">
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon3">
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon4">
    </div>
    <div class="single-icon-container">
      <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/50e4d646434faa0df7c5d57bc32f3e7b1d3ac3e45551784c722f78d79e_640.jpg" alt="" class="icon" id="icon5">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Also just to share -- I had to add a height/width of 225px to the main container, as well as a border, so that all the images were inside a box. At that point, the negative margin on the images made the image container look off-center. I was able to fix it by adding `margin-left: -15px` on the parent container for images ('main-container').